# Laravel api logout user for inactivity

Tags: laravel, api

I am using 'auth:api' guard to handle user authentication and wondering is there any built in feature like 'session.lifetime' to logout user after X minutes of inactivity or should I create custom middleware to logout them.

Thank you for your responses in advance!

Comment: api authentication is for every request. There is not lifetime for this authentication type.

Comment: I hope there is a way. At least one can create middleware to logout authenticated user in the next request followed by x minutes of inactivity.

Comment: the problem is with you continuing to say 'logged in/logout' ... no session, no concept of being logged in

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do this using the default `API Guard` driver, only via session or using an `OAuth` approach.

First of all I suggests you to implement an OAuth authentication, see how to this via Passport here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/passport.

After this I suggest to create a middleware that updates the `access_token`'s `expires_in` column to a new value on your need, because the original implementation expires based on the time that the token was created.

Comment: Laravel Documentation: The expires_at columns on Passport's database tables are read-only and for display purposes only. When issuing tokens, Passport stores the expiration information within the signed and encrypted tokens. If you need to invalidate a token you should revoke it. So updating expires_at not working.